# ANTLR4: How to generate a graphic of the parse tree when using a Python target?

Tags: python, python-2.7, antlr, antlr4

When using `Java-ANTLR` I can use the `testrig` with the `-gui` flag and generate a nice graphic of the parse tree.

I am now using `Python-ANTLR`. Is there a `testrig` available with a `-gui` flag that allows me to see a nice graphic of the parse tree?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841151/antrl4-cant-get-python-antlr-to-generate-a-graphic-of-the-parse-tree