# ANTRL4: Can't get Python ANTLR to generate a graphic of the parse tree

Tags: java, python, antlr, antlr4

I have a simple `HelloWorld.g4` grammar (see it at the bottom). I am able to successfully generate the `.py` files using this:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;antlr-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

java org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Python2 HelloWorld.g4
```

Now I would like to use the `TestRig` with the `-gui` flag to generate a parse tree GUI. I have the ANTRL Python runtime installed (`antlr4-python2-runtime-4.5.tar.gz`). I can open a Python interpreter and type:

```
import antlr4
```

and  the interpreter recognizes the `antlr4` module.

When I run the `TestRig` like this:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;antlr-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig HelloWorld message -gui < input.txt
```

I get this error message:

```
Can't load HelloWorld as lexer or parser
```

From my investigations I have found several posts listing the same error message. However, in those cases they forgot to include period (.) in their classpath. But as you can see, I have included it in my classpath.

I'm out of ideas on how to get the `TestRig` to work. Note: I have no problem getting the `TestRig` to work with the same `HelloWorld` grammar when the target language is Java.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

**HelloWorld.g4**

```
grammar HelloWorld;   

options { language=Python; }            

message   : GREETING NAME;

GREETING : 'Hello' ;    
NAME     : [a-zA-Z]+ ;                      
WS       : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ran into this today as well: The problem is that the testrig expects the generated java source code. But since you're on Python you don't have it unless you explicitly run `antlr4` twice: Once for target language Python2 (or 3) and once for `-Dlanguage=java`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23316075/923794) which suggests to run the `language=java` target first. Then the comment on [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315302/antlr4-cant-load-hello-as-lexer-or-parser) to compile the java files.

And for completeness and before it's forgotten: Ensure your `$CLASSPATH` env variable is set up so that it includes both a dot `'.'` and the path to the `antlr*.jar` file. [For example on unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315302/antlr4-cant-load-hello-as-lexer-or-parser):

```
export CLASSPATH=".:/<Mydirectory>/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
```

Here's a step by step of what I guess you have to do once the `$CLASSPATH` is set correctly:

Compile for java:

```
> antlr4 -Dlanguage=Java HelloWorld.g4
# or:  java org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Java HelloWorld.g4
```

Note that I have the `options { language=Python3 }` in my grammar file and the `-D` override did not work as expected. So I removed the option block and specify the language target on the command line now.

Then compile the `*.java` files into `*.class` files:

```
> javac -g *.java
```

Then run the testrig:

```
> grun HelloWorld message
# or: java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig HelloWorld message -gui < input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the message cfi. It shouldn't be necessary to generate the parse tree graphic from Java classes. I know at least one person in this world who has generated the parse tree graphic by applying testrig to the Python files: https://github.com/godber/pds3_grammar/ (scroll down to the bottom of the page and you will see a beautiful "Parse Tree Inspector" graphic. I've been in touch with the follow who created that and showed him what I did (described in my above post) and he doesn't see anything wrong. This is a mystery indeed. I wish that Terrance Parr would chime in on this issue.

Comment: That's interesting information, but did you try out my suggestion? Even if there might be a simpler way, this was what worked for me (and others as well). So it's worth a try. Or is there a reason why you could not accept this - even if it is just a workaround? Are there other constraints? Running the `antlr4` tool twice is no real impact, imho. A small script, and you'll never notice again.

Comment: Note that the guy *does* build java targets. See the [makefile](https://github.com/godber/pds3_grammar/blob/master/antlr_grammar/Makefile), and he does compile them into `*.class` files, and thus he does it exactly in the way I described and thus he does not have an issue ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much cfi. I see what you mean. Yes, he does run testrig on the Java .class files, not on the Python.class files. I didn't catch that when reading his makefile. Thanks again!