# ANTLR4: How can Java execute Python files?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, antlr, antlr4

I am using ANTLR to generate a Python lexer/parser (a.k.a. `Python target`).

The official ANTLR page says: use Java to generate `.py` files:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;antlr-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

java org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Python2 HelloWorld.g4
```

Okay, that worked fine. A bunch of `.py` files were generated: `HelloWorldLexer.py`, `HelloWorldParser.py`, etc.

The ANTLR page then says: a graphic of the parse tree can be generated by applying Java to the `.py` files:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;antlr-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig HelloWorld message -gui < input.txt
```

That doesn't work, it generates this error: `Can't load HelloWorld as lexer or parser`

Aside from the small problem that it doesn't work (for me), how in the world can Java execute `.py` files? Somehow Java must be firing up and using the Python interpreter? Perhaps if I got a better idea how Java is applied to Python files, I can figure out why I am getting the above error message. Any insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated. This is a related SO post: [ANTRL4: Can't get Python ANTLR to generate a graphic of the parse tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841151/antrl4-cant-get-python-antlr-to-generate-a-graphic-of-the-parse-tree)

P.S. I installed the ANTLR Python runtime (`antlr4-python2-runtime-4.5.tar.gz`) prior to doing the above.

Comment: it would help if you link the page that says so

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice? Although some might consider this not be an exact duplicate: What you assume to happen does not happen. As I explained in my answer to your other question, you must first compile the java target, compile the `*.java` files into `*.class` files and then the testrig inspects those. So your question here is somewhat obsolete.